# R loop over the data frame and plot

Tags: r

I am asking question that was probably asked before. However, I was not able to find answer that I could adjust to my data.

Example of my data:

```
State  V1         V2       V3  
2   0.00000     0.0000   12.2661
4   0.00000     0.0000   21.3610
3   2.15633     0.0000    0.0000
3  28.07880    33.0049   30.7882
2   0.00000     0.0000    0.0000
6   0.00000     7.3000   33.6100
2   1.00000     0.0000   10.2503
4   0.00000     5.0000   56.3410
3   2.15633     0.0000    0.0000
6   8.07880    43.0049   15.8002
2   0.40000     0.0000    0.0000
2   0.00000     0.0000   23.1000
```

I want to: for every `State`(2,3,4,6), plot every `Variable`(V1,V2,V3).

I am able to get want I want using this code:

```
s2 <- subset(df, State == 2)
s3 <- subset(df, State == 3)
s4 <- subset(df, State == 4)
s6 <- subset(df, State == 6) 

jpeg('rplot_V1.jpg')
boxplot(s2$V1,s3$V1,s4$V1,s6$V1)  
dev.off()
jpeg('rplot_V2.jpg')
boxplot(s2$V2,s3$V2,s4$V2,s6$V2)  
dev.off()
jpeg('rplot_V3.jpg')
boxplot(s2$V3,s3$V3,s4$V3,s6$V3)  
dev.off()
```

This solution is clumsy when data-frame is 10 times larger.
**My question:** How to loop over the data frame and print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="State  V1         V2       V3  
2   0.00000     0.0000   12.2661
4   0.00000     0.0000   21.3610
3   2.15633     0.0000    0.0000
3  28.07880    33.0049   30.7882
2   0.00000     0.0000    0.0000
6   0.00000     7.3000   33.6100
2   1.00000     0.0000   10.2503
4   0.00000     5.0000   56.3410
3   2.15633     0.0000    0.0000
6   8.07880    43.0049   15.8002
2   0.40000     0.0000    0.0000
2   0.00000     0.0000   23.1000", header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)

#plot boxplot
lapply(2:ncol(df),function(i){
  jpeg(paste0(paste("State",colnames(df)[i],sep="~"),".jpeg"))
  boxplot(df[,i]~df$State,
          ylab="State",
          xlab=colnames(df)[i],
          main=paste("State",colnames(df)[i],sep="~"))
  dev.off()
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after

```
states <- unique(test$State)           #if your data.frame is called `test`

for(i in 1:length(states)){
  boxplot(test[test$State == states[i],2:4])  
}
```

Edit after comment by OP

If you want to plot states 1, 2 and >=3 you can easily do this by temporarily creating another data.frame (tmp) and manipulate the State values. Then you can just use the same loop as described above.

```
tmp <- test

tmp$State[tmp$State >= 3] <- 3

states <- unique(tmp$State)

for(i in 1:length(states)){
  boxplot(test[test$State == states[i],2:4])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I want to group `States` like this: `1`,`2`,`3`, larger than 3 (`> 3`)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change your data.frame accordingly or you just want to plot it that way?

Comment: One more thing. Probably I didn't explained it well. Your solution plots for every `State` Variables. However, I tried to `boxplot` for every `State` specific `variable` in one plot.